# bootstrap slider isn't working using dom

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to dynamically create bootstrap slider, so I decided to using dom to create one.

Now my js code is like this:

```
  const newItem = document.createElement('input');
  newItem.setAttribute('id', 'slider');
  newItem.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-provide', 'slider');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-min', '1');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-max', '3');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-step', '1');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-value', '1');
  newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-tooltip', 'hide');
```

But it only displays a text box, I use Chrome dev tool to inspect the element, it looks like this:

```
<input id="slider" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="3" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="1" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
```

My configuration seems right because I create a slider successfully using html, like this:

```
    <input
        type="text"
        data-provide="slider"
        data-slider-min="1"
        data-slider-max="3"
        data-slider-step="1"
        data-slider-value="3"
        data-slider-tooltip="hide"
    >
```

In [bootstrap-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-slider), it said:

> Create an input element with the data-provide="slider" attribute
>   automatically turns it into a slider.

So the problem seems like that bootstrap-slider did not interpret my attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to initialize your slider something like this (if you're not using jQuery):

```
// Instantiate a slider
var mySlider = new Slider(newItem, {
   // initial options object
   step: 1,    
   min: 1,
   max:3,
   value: 1,
   tooltip: 'hide'
});
```

So, In your case, if you also want to build a dynamic input and then attach a slider to it, your whole code would look like this:

```
// Create an input element dynamically
var newItem = document.createElement('input');

const body = document.querySelector('body');
// Add your new created element to body (or any other div)
body.appendChild(newItem);

// Instantiate a slider
var mySlider = new Slider(newItem, {
   // initial options object
   step: 1,    
   min: 1,
   max:3,
   value: 1,
   tooltip: 'hide'
 });
```

Here I built a live demo for you: [https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekraj007/hdr253xb](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekraj007/hdr253xb/6/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
        $(function () {
            var newItem = document.createElement('input');
            newItem.setAttribute('id', 'slider');
            newItem.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-provide', 'slider');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-min', '1');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-max', '3');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-step', '1');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-value', '1');
            newItem.setAttribute('data-slider-tooltip', 'hide');
            document.body.appendChild(newItem);
            $(newItem).slider();
        });
```

```css
body{ padding: 10px;}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
```